# Iterate over string array

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting this `string[]`

[image]

but when I iterate over it

```
subUrl(arr) {
        for(let i of arr) { console.log(i); }
}
```

It isn't logging anything. What's wrong?

Comment: can you provide the result of `JSON.stringify(obj)` where `obj` is your array object?

Answer (score 3):

Your data is an array inside array,  you need two loops

```
   for (let firstarray of arr){
       for (let i of firstarray ){
          console.log(i);
       }
    }
```

Comment: can you debug and see

Comment: I put `console.log` inside of these two for and not a single result was written..

Comment: when I log arr.length it says 0

Comment: just post what is inside console.log(arr);

Comment: picture which I have in my question is console.log(arr); I'm getting that using `@Output ` and that's what arr looks like.

I want to join these data in another array and that's why I want to iterate over that